# How to resolve Win32 error 1069 when starting cron under cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, cron

The machine runs Windows 7 Home edition.  I'm trying to use rsync to backup files to a linux box.  The rsync command runs fine in cygwin.  I resolved an earlier error by running the cygwin terminal as Administrator.  Here's what I see:

```
Helen@Helen-PC ~
$ cron-config
Cron is already installed as a service under account .\Helen.
Do you want to remove or reinstall it? (yes/no) no
Running cron_diagnose ...
... no problem found.

cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: StartService:  Win32 error 1069:
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

Here are what I'm guessing are the most important bits from cronbug.txt:

```
Current version
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Helen None 5304 Feb 15  2010 /usr/share/doc/Cygwin/cron-4.1-59.README

Running crons:
None

Crontabs:
-rw-r----- 1 Helen root 431 Apr 27 09:09 /var/cron/tabs/Helen

Service             : cron
Display name        : Cron daemon
Current State       : Stopped
Command             : /usr/sbin/cron -n
stdin path          : /dev/null
stdout path         : /var/log/cron.log
stderr path         : /var/log/cron.log
Environment         : CYGWIN=" " 
Process Type        : Own Process
Startup             : Automatic
Account             : .\Helen
```

`/var/log/cron.log` doesn't exists but `Helen` owns the directory.  I get the same error message when I try to start cron directly, e.g. `net start cron`.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realize now what I did wrong.  When I originally ran `cron-config`, I entered the wrong password for the `Helen` account.  I didn't realize this password was saved in some way for starting the daemon.

To fix, I ran `cron-config`, answered `yes` to `Do you want to remove or reinstall it?`, then answered `yes` to the install and start questions.  Output of `cron-config` included: `The cron daemon is now running.` and I confirmed by setting my rsync command to run a few minutes in the future.  The rsync happened as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well with cygwin on Windows 10 almost 8 years later. The problem is my account is a Microsoft Account (not local), and even if I tried to change my local account password [using power shell](https://adamtheautomator.com/reset-windows-10-password-command-prompt/), neither my Microsoft nor local password no my Sign-on PIN ever worked in starting the service. All returned "Win32 error 1069".

I ended up changing the "Cron daemon" service properties to use a Local System account, and this did the trick for me (Services -> "Cron daemon" -> Properties -> Log On). I tested by having cron run a script in my home directory.

- Use `ps -ef | grep cron` to check if the service is running

Versions:

- Windows 10
- Cygwin64 3.1.7-1
- cron 4.1-65